# ClickOnce post-deployment action not working with DevExpress

Tags: ms-word, devexpress, vsto, clickonce

I have a VSTO, *application-level*, Word add-in that uses DevExpress Winforms components. Deployment is done with ClickOnce and everything works well.

Recently I added a **post-deployment action** to ClickOnce for copying some files to the user's computer after installation/update, following [MS guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961899%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that, although presented for document-level add-ins, do not say anything explicit about it not being suitable for application-level solutions.

I implemented the code to copy some files after installation completes (without the *AddCustomization()* part), published the app, edited and re-signed the manifests to add the post-deployment action, and upon testing it, it worked as intended --but only on development machines that have DevExpress installed. On a user machine, installation fails saying it can't find a DevExpress module or one of its dependencies.

Summary:

- Normal ClickOnce installer works properly.
- Installer with post-deploy action added fails with following error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'DevExpress.XtraEditors.v14.1, Version=14.1.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Adding the post-deployment action breaks the installer and so far I didn't find any information on why this happens. (Maybe PDAs are intended for document-level add-ins only, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.)

Any ideas on how to solve this or why it doesn't (or won't) work?

Comment: Check the Application Files window in the ClickOnce/Publish tab of Visual Studio and make sure the DevExpress assmblies are set to "Include" or "Include (Auto)" and NOT "Prerequesite".

Comment: Forgot to mention this is a VS2010 project (for compatibility with Word 2007+). *Publish* tab on *Properties* only shows *Prerequisites* configuration and no *Application Files* window. Not sure if there's another way to achieve that. Thanks anyway!